# getting a string from a listview item in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview

I was wondering how I can get a string from a clicked listview's item. For example I have an entry in this format.

# - John Smith

john@gmail.com

3451234532

New York

I want to get John Smith. I can get the item on that position but I don't know the rest.

My codes:

```
package com.example.deneme;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Activity2 extends Activity {

private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
 ListView listContent;
 SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
 Cursor cursor;
 Button buttonDeleteAll,buttonDeleteRow;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity2);


buttonDeleteAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteall);
buttonDeleteRow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleterow); 
listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
listContent.setClickable(true);
buttonDeleteAll.setOnClickListener(buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener);
buttonDeleteRow.setOnClickListener(buttonDeleteRowOnClickListener);


mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();



cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
String[] from = new String[]{ SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_NAME, SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_EMAIL,SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_PHONE, SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_ADDRESS};

int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2,R.id.text3, R.id.text4};

cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);



listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

        String str = ((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});



}


   Button.OnClickListener buttonDeleteRowOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

       public void onClick(View arg0) {

     //    String n = inputContent1.getText().toString();
     //    mySQLiteAdapter.deleteRow(n);
           updateList();
           Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Entry Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      


       }
        };

        Button.OnClickListener buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View arg0) {

        mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
        updateList();
        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "All Entries Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      

       }
        };

        private void updateList(){
              cursor.requery();
               }
}
```

After using your way, I got hese errors:

```
07-27 07:52:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 07:52:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.ClassCastException:              android.widget.LinearLayout
07-27 07:52:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at  com.example.deneme.Activity2$3.onItemClick(Activity2.java:58)
07-27 07:52:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-27 07:52:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
07-27 07:52:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
```

Comment: that error might be because the view is a linear layout and you are trying to cast it to a textView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you've populated your listview with. If those are TextView's then all you have to do is this:

```
((TextView)arg1).getText().toString()
```

Essentially `View arg1` is the clicked View. Given that you've populated that list, you know what that view is, because you're the one who created and returned it in(in your adapter):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Therefore, whatever the type of that View, check its the documentation to see how to get the text out of it

### Edit:

Well, the cursor adapter you're using returns a LinearLayout for each row. It has several TextViews, one for each column that's selected. To get the first column you do this:

```
LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)arg1).getChildAt(0);
TextView column = (TextView)row.getChildAt(0);
String text = column.getText().toString();
```

If you want a different column just change the argument to `getChildAt(i)`

Comment: all of them are TextViews, I tried ((TextView)arg1).getText().toString(), it gives error

Comment: are you using a custom adapter, in that case what is the type of object  each listview item is?

Comment: for getChild there is no method getText. I think I should another method there.

Comment: there is a master linearlayout then there is another linearlayout inside of it. And textview for name is inside of this linearloyout

Comment: ok i did it. I just add another LinearLayout row and I got its child. Thanks mate

Comment: I edited the code one last time, is that the form that works? Also, glad to be of help

Answer (score 3):

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_EMAIL));
        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text, just use

```
String item = ((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
```

On another note, it would be helpful if you rename the arguments of the function you implement like:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id)
```

Now you can clearly see what each parameter does.