# Android: Searching in list using array adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My problem here is when I scroll the words manually select it from the list, it correctly displays the definition. However, when I type it and search for the definition, it always shows the first item of my list. I'm currently learning android by going through tutorials and came across this example but couldn't fix  the bug. Here is my code:

[Here's my output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEHLp.png)

```
public class DbBackend extends DbObject{

    public DbBackend(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public String[] dictionaryWords(){
        String query = "Select * from dictionary";
        Cursor cursor = this.getDbConnection().rawQuery(query, null);
        ArrayList<String> wordTerms = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));
                wordTerms.add(word);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        String[] dictionaryWords = new String[wordTerms.size()];
        dictionaryWords = wordTerms.toArray(dictionaryWords);
        return dictionaryWords;
    }

//
//    public int getIndexByValue(String value){
//        S
//    }
    public QuizObject getQuizById(int quizId){

        QuizObject quizObject = null;
        String query = "select * from dictionary where _id = " + quizId;
        Cursor cursor = this.getDbConnection().rawQuery(query, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));
                String meaning = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("meaning"));
                quizObject = new QuizObject(word, meaning);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return quizObject;
    }
}
```

Here's the Dictionary activity

```
public class DictionaryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView wordMeaning;
    private TextToSpeech convertToSpeech;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        int dictionaryId = bundle.getInt("DICTIONARY_ID");
        int id = dictionaryId + 1;

        TextView word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.word);
        wordMeaning = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dictionary);
        Button textToSpeech = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        DbBackend dbBackend = new DbBackend(DictionaryActivity.this);
        QuizObject allQuizQuestions = dbBackend.getQuizById(id);

        word.setText(allQuizQuestions.getWord());
        wordMeaning.setText(allQuizQuestions.getDefinition());



    }
```

Another class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText filterText;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        DbBackend dbBackend = new DbBackend(MainActivity.this);
        String[] terms = dbBackend.dictionaryWords();

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, terms);

        itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // make Toast when click
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DictionaryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, much of which seems unrelated to your problem. Please try to narrow down what part of the code doesn't seem to be doing what you intend it to. If you can't narrow it down from all of what you posted, that suggests you haven't really spent enough time trying to solve it. A good place to start would be the place where the item is clicked.

Comment: My apologies for copy pasting everything. I have narrow down the code now.I tried looking into the code I found out that the position of my list is not moving. No matter what I search for, my MainAcitivity class is always sending a position value of zero to another display activity, and displays the first item from the list. Perhaps, the value of position hasn't been updated. Should  I pass the id instead of position?

Comment: The position refers to where it is in the adapter, not where it is in your database. When the list is filtered, the adapter saves away the original list and swaps it with a list that has only the items matching the filter term. The adapter is correctly reporting that the position is zero. Since positions do not identify data, you need to use something else to identify the data at that position.

Comment: Okay so you are saying I should retrieve the word by using id instead of position?

Comment: I was thinking may be I should change my query and search for word instead of id by doing this.

Comment: String query = "select * from dictionary where word = " + editText;                                  and retrieve values.

Comment: Searching by word itself would work, and I believe this is what Juan Salamanca's answer suggests. The problem is `ArrayAdapter` uses the `position` as the id, so the `id` you are given is not the id of the row in the database for that word. If you had a wrapper class to contain  the word and it's database id, and stored that in the adapter instead, you could make `getitemId` return the proper id. But you would have to modify the adapter a lot more, at which point I'd say extend `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter` (I almost never use `ArrayAdapter` for reasons like this one).

Comment: Okay I tried this line of code in onItemClick:                                                                   String selected = terms[position];                            intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", selected);                    and also changed the query to                                                                            String query = "select * from dictionary where word = '" + quizId;                       But it gave this error message  :      QuizObject.getWord()' on a null object

Answer (score 2):

In this part try to get the word not the id

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // make Toast when click
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String selectedText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DictionaryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", selectedText);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

and the query

```
String query = "select * from dictionary where _id = " + quizId;
```

replace by

```
String query = "select * from dictionary where word = '" + quizId + "';
```

remenber the quizId now is the word in the position of your list,

Comment: Isn't it same to pass either id or word since both are from the same row?

Comment: So you are saying to do this ?                                                                       String selected = terms[position];                                                                                       intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", selected);

Comment: When I changed the query to word, it is throwing this error message       QuizObject.getWord()' on a null object reference

Comment: try with the view

Comment: Do you mean the textview?

Comment: im sorry yes.. try with the view in setOnItemClickListener  TextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);  try to get the text of the item and pass to the query

Comment: I'm sorry how do I get the text of the item and pass it to query?

Comment: use this   String str = ((TextView)view ).getText().toString();  in setonitemclicklistener metod the full answer is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683547/getting-a-string-from-a-listview-item-in-setonitemclicklistener

Comment: I tried this code from the link you directed me                                 TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)view).getChildAt(0);
                textView = (TextView)row.getChildAt(0);
                String text = textView.getText().toString();                                  I got this error message :                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID",text);   // The text was passed onto another activity like this